# Time limit exceeded error when doing left shift with boost::multiprecision cpp_int

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying the following:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;
   cpp_int v = 1;
   unsigned int a = 4294967295;
   std::cout << (v << a) << std::endl; 
   return 0;
}
```

How to prevent errors in the same?
What is the upper limit of bit shift that we can do with cpp_int.

Comment: Well, number 2^(2^32 - 1) is just enormously big. I don't know what exactly running time are you expecting, but even displaying so many digits will take you some time (it has about 2*10^9 digits, printing it on normal computer will take at least 10 seconds).

Comment: Time limit exceeded generally means your solution is too slow. If the goal is to shift a bit 4 billion places, youch. There has to be some extra information that will suggest a trick you can use to reduce the amount of work.

Comment: @Maras It's actually pretty fast (7.4s on my machine) but it writes 1.3GiB of decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is allocating huge amounts of (wasted) memory.

Since you can use decimal floating numbers to represent this number without any loss of precision, I'd do that:

Note that `1 << n` is equal to `2^n` (pow(2, n)), so you can write:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmp = boost::multiprecision;
using number = bmp::number<bmp::cpp_dec_float<50, intmax_t> >;

int main() {
    int64_t a = 0xffffffff;
    std::cout << pow(number(2), a) << std::endl; 
}
```

Which gets the correct

```
1.55164e+1292913986
```

You can verify it is correct:

```
for (intmax_t const a : { -8888ll, 0xFFFFll, 0xFFFFFFFFll, }) {
    std::cout << pow(number(2), a) << std::endl; 
    auto roundtrip_exponent = bmp::log2(pow(number(2), a));

    auto reverse = round(roundtrip_exponent).convert_to<intmax_t>();
    std::cout << "Reverse: " << std::hex << std::showbase << reverse << std::dec << "\n";

    std::cout << "Match: " << std::boolalpha << (a == reverse) << "\n";
}
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9fe62904282042d)**

```
2.78868e-2676
Reverse: 0xffffffffffffdd48
Match: true
1.00176e+19728
Reverse: 0xffff
Match: true
1.55164e+1292913986
Reverse: 0xffffffff
Match: true
```

You'll inevitably lose some precision on the inexact operations (log2) in the extreme cases.

If you're curious you may want to try to print the full precision by setting `std::fixed`:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmp = boost::multiprecision;
using number = bmp::number<bmp::cpp_dec_float<50, intmax_t> >;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << pow(number(2), 0xFFFFFFFFll) << std::endl; 
}
```

Redirect the output to a file! It's gonna write 1.3GiB in decimal digits. This should explain why it didn't work too well with the arbitrary precision integer representation.

All of the output compresses to:

```
0000000 3531 3135 3436 3230 3137 3339 3631 3334
0000020 3730 3130 3934 3439 3535 3737 3339 3831
0000040 3232 3937 3535 3631 3334 3936 3939 3038
0000060 3737 3938 3631 3338 3737 3030 3532 3339
0000100 3533 3538 3636 3230 3935 3039 3030 3030
0000120 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030
*
11504046500 3030 2e30 3030 3030 3030 000a
11504046513
```

Where the `*` denotes lines with only 0 digits. Then you can see why I called it wasteful